# Is it possible to open an Sqlite database with Javascript and not using anything but HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I'm trying to create an application that works on any mobile device, but doesn't require internet.  I want to have an Sqlite database that I can query.  I found a script, but it creates a WebSQL database in the browser.  I want to query the flatfile.  Is that even possible?

Here is my code:

```
function createDatabase() {
    try{
        if (window.openDatabase) {
            var db;
            var shortName = 'configurator.sqlite';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'configurator';
            var maxSize = 65335;

            db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
        } else {
            console.log('failure');
        }
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: so you do or dont want to use WebSQL?

Comment: WebSQL has been deprecated.  I want to use something else.  Is Indexed DB my only choice?  I want to work with the SQLite file.

Comment: as you stated WebSQL, the implementation of SQLite in Web Browser, is deprecated, so if you really need to use that format i can only suggest to use this [SQL.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Its possible. Try the following links

- http://benpoole.com/weblog/201106222227
- https://gist.github.com/1041277
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase.html

Comment: Those are WebSQL, which has been deprecated.

Comment: Is HTML5 localStorage a solution for you?

Comment: I wanted something where it was relational, and I don't believe HTML5 localStorage is.

Comment: Yes, you are right. localStorage is not relational just a key-value pair. I doubt there is any other solution that will work in all browser at that moment. You can think of IndexedDB but I think its supported only in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

The question is asking for someone who can provide a tutorial to query a FlatFile DB and not a web db embedded within the browser. All your links are providing tutorial on Web DB which the question clearly highlights.

I think you should research SQL.JS on Github to get a solution to what you want. It is somewhat dependent on Node.js but you will achieve your goal just fine.

Comment: This is better-suited as a comment, since it doesn't provide a concrete answer.